# Every periodic Function can be rewritten as a sum of alternarnations of itself

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

I am currently writing an essay on applications of complex analysis in number theory and I got to prove the product representation of the sinus function. In the proof that I am reading the author says that if g(x) is a periodic function then g(x) is the same as 1/4 (g(x/2) + g((x+1)/2)). It seems simplistic but yet I can't figure out where it comes from.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is alternarnation?

Comment: $\sin x\ne (\sin\frac x2+\sin\frac{x+1}2)/4 $

Comment: Let g(x) be a periodic function that is equal
the second derivative of log φ(x) where φ(x) is Γ(1 + x)Γ(1 − x)*(x^-1 ( the maclaurin explantion of sin(x)).

Comment: @JeanMarie I didn't mean to write it as integer part of I just used it as brackets since I didn't want to have the same brackets. My bad here.

Comment: Sorry, but this identity is erroneous.

Comment: @JeanMarie here is the paper I am looking at https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-104-seminar-in-analysis-applications-to-number-theory-fall-2006/projects/chan.pdf. Page 5. It could be my bad but can you please have a look? Thanks

Comment: I have had a look and I still not understand. The only vague analog I have seen (for a 8-periodical function...) is https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2088809

Comment: Let us "requalify" the identity you give, 
$$g(x)=\frac14\left(g(\tfrac{x}{2})+g(\tfrac{x+1}{2})\right)$$
as a **functional equation**. What are its solutions ? Surely not all periodical functions. I am asking myself whether there is even a nonzero solution...

Comment: @JeanMarie according to the paper for all x g(x) is 0 yet periodic which makes little sense to me. Is it possible that the paper is just wrong?

Comment: You cannot exclude that an accompanying condition has been forgotten ... Sttange  for an OCW / MIT usual standards.

Comment: @JeanMarie, to be honest, the paper is not dealing with any complicated theorems or ideas. I just find the analogy a little strange.

Comment: I just saw that this text is the work of a student. The best proof that this result is **completely flawed** is that the identity should be valid for constant functions, which is not the case...